# How to reduct or hide specific line output after execution bash command?

Tags: bash, shell

For example, I run command with params

```
# ./nonmyprogram
```

and it prints out some useful info and secret

```
Your ID: 1234
Secret ID: qwerty
Some other: data
```

I want to add some output transformation so i will get:

```
Your ID: 1234
Some other: data
```

or

```
Your ID: 1234
Secret ID: [redacted]
Some other: data
```

Comment: Can you not stop the Secret ID from printing within the myprogram script?

Comment: unfortunately, had to name it as ./nonmyprogram

Comment: ./nonmyprogram | grep -v '^Secret ID:'?